# Logstash daily index wrong date format for next month

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, logstash

I have got a year worth of data that I have been indexing daily, today when I check my indexes there's something wrong with naming, the next month `day` format won't return back to `1` instead it incremented from the previous month `31 + 1` = 32.

```
measurements-2016-01-01
...
..
.
measurements-2016-01-30
measurements-2016-01-31
measurements-2016-02-32 <== WRONG. Should be 1
measurements-2016-02-33 <== WRONG. Should be 2
measurements-2016-02-34 <== WRONG. Should be 3
...
..
.
```

I have tried to edit my logstash output to `YYYY-MM-DD` but it doesn't work either.

My logstash configuration

```
input {
    file {
        path => "measurements.txt"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    }
}
filter {
    csv {
        separator => ","
        columns => ["Id", "Recorded_Date", "Units", "Description", "cpu"]
    }

    date {
        match => [ "Recorded_Date", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }

    mutate {convert => ["Id", "integer"]}
    mutate {convert => ["Units", "float"]}
    mutate {convert => ["cpu", "float"]}
}

output {
    elasticsearch{
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
        index => "measurements-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}"
    }
    stdout {}
}
```

On February, it should be:

```
measurements-2016-02-01
measurements-2016-02-02
measurements-2016-02-03
```

Instead

Comment: "dd" is day of the month, and should work.  "DD" is day of the year and would give results as you describe.

Comment: So it should be "measurements-%{+YYYY-MM-DD}" ?

Comment: "dd" didn't work though, it gave me 02-32, 02-33

Comment: What version are you using? The correct pattern to daily index is really `%{+YYYY-MM-dd}`, it should work. Did you restarted the service after changing the configuration?

Comment: I'm running Logstash 7.0.1. I have restarted it's still the same. Tried removing `-dd` and it did return `2016-02` without the day. So the service had restarted.

Comment: Do you have any other pipeline being loaded that could have the old configuration? If this is your only pipeline and it is already using `%{+YYYY-MM-dd}` and it is still not working I would recommend to open a bug on Logstash's Github.